# installing apache mod_ssl with latest openssl version (/usr/local/openssl)

Tags: apache, openssl, mod-ssl

I need to update my apache 2.2.21 installation to use the latest openssl version.
But somehow it just keeps using 0.9.8k. (according to server-status).

I followed this guide and compiled apache with the custom ssl path:
http://hulan.info/item/compile-apache-with-ssl-php-5-and-mysql-on-linux

It still says: 
Server Version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8k DAV/2
Server Built: Mar 8 2012 10:17:02

Can anyone help me? 
How can you let mod_ssl use the latest openssl version?

Comment: For me it worked when I used --with-ssl=openssl_src_path

Comment: I think this question is off-topic for stackoverflow, it might be more relevant for serverfault, superuser or unix StackExchange sites.